# Which Laravel feature to use for checking logical condition before delete/store operations on models?

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, middleware, lumen

I want to perform delete operations on models but do a check (apart from user authorization) to see whether this operations is allowed.

`For example in a billing app, a user must first revert a delivery made before being able to delete a bill.`

Several models require similar checks. I am considering using either Middleware or Policies.

Which one would be preferrable?

Comment: One option is to push the logic down to the model level by hooking into the Model's "deleting" event. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events

Comment: Check for [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization) - easiest way to allow or deny operations on models.

Comment: I am considering policies, omitted in details. Have added it.